# BASH Script, running a command across all files created by split -l

Tags: bash, split

I want to create a bash script that runs a command across ALL files that are created by the split -l command.  Then delete the file after it is processed.

The default naming structure is x**

How would I go about doing this?  The number of x** files will vary.

The reason I want to do this is because when running the command that I want the BASH script to run, it does not process large files efficiently.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Does `x**` mean `x` with some number of other characters after it? Does the bash script accept more than one file as argument?

Comment: character after it--first answer would work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for fname in x[a-z][a-z]
do
    command-you-want-to-run "$fname" && rm "$fname"
done
```

By default, `split` produces alphabetical suffixes of length 2.  Thus the file glob above is limited to `x[a-z][a-z]`.  This helps limit the possibility that unrelated files, whose names just happen to start with `x`, will be processed and erased.

Comment: This will delete "$fname" even if `command-you-want-to-run` fails.

Comment: to expand on this, is there a way to run a command on a value that is the actual file on a per line basis? (thank you btw)

Comment: @brizz Probably.  Could you clarify?  Is it that you want to provide each line from a file as an argument to some command?  Or, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
for file in x*; do
  ./yourscript "$file" && rm "$file"
done
```

or maybe

```
./yourscript x* && rm x*
```

Depending on how ./yourscript is designed.